# How to drop duplicates in Data Frame based on combination of values in 2 columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [999, 999, 999, 185, 185, 185, 999, 999, 999],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'event': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'survey': ['2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-22'],
    'event1': [1, 6, 11, 16, np.nan, 22, 74, 109, 52],
    'event2': [2, 7, np.nan, 17, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 5],
    'event3': [3, 8, 13, 18, 23, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 99],
    'event4': [4, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11, 8, np.nan, np.nan],
    'event5': [5, np.nan, 15, 20, 25, 1, 1, 3, np.nan]
})

df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

**Requirements:**

And I need to remain in my Data Frame not duplicated values in column "id" remaining also all rows with not duplicated values from column "survey" for that id.

So, for example as you can see in example for id = 999 we have in column "survey" value 2023-02-02 or 2023-04-22, so I need to stay all rows for id = 999 with 2023-02-02 or with 2023-04-022.

**Example of needed result:**

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [999, 999, 999, 185, 185, 185],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'event': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'survey': ['2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10'],
    'event1': [1, 6, 11, 16, np.nan, 22],
    'event2': [2, 7, np.nan, 17, 22, np.nan],
    'event3': [3, 8, 13, 18, 23, np.nan],
    'event4': [4, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11],
    'event5': [5, np.nan, 15, 20, 25, 1]
})

df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the first survey date per id with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = df[df.groupby('id')['survey'].transform('first').eq(df['survey'])]
```

Output:

```
    id  target       event      survey  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
0  999       1  2023-01-01  2023-02-02     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
1  999       1  2023-01-02  2023-02-02     6.0     7.0     8.0     9.0     0.0
2  999       1  2023-02-03  2023-02-02    11.0     0.0    13.0     0.0    15.0
3  185       0  2023-01-01  2023-03-10    16.0    17.0    18.0     0.0    20.0
4  185       0  2023-01-02  2023-03-10     0.0    22.0    23.0     0.0    25.0
5  185       0  2023-01-03  2023-03-10    22.0     0.0     0.0    11.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mask = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
df = df[(df['id'].isin(mask['id'])) &
   (df['survey'].isin(mask['survey']))]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id  target  event   survey      event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
0   999 1   2023-01-01  2023-02-02  1.0      2.0    3.0      4.0    5.0
1   999 1   2023-01-02  2023-02-02  6.0      7.0    8.0      9.0    0.0
2   999 1   2023-02-03  2023-02-02  11.0     0.0    13.0     0.0    15.0
3   185 0   2023-01-01  2023-03-10  16.0     17.0   18.0     0.0    20.0
4   185 0   2023-01-02  2023-03-10  0.0      22.0   23.0     0.0    25.0
5   185 0   2023-01-03  2023-03-10  22.0     0.0    0.0      11.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the requirements correctly, you should be able to simply use the `.drop_duplicates()` method along with the `subset` argument. In your case, this would be something like:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'event'])`

This will drop rows where another row with the same `id` and `event` value already exist.